# How to duplicate lines in Python

Tags: python, string

I have `print (5*"@")`, which gives me:

```
@@@@@
```

Now if I add `\n` to it, `print (5*"@\n")`, it gives me five lines consisting of one `@` each.

What do I do when I want it to give me this:

Four lines consisting of five `@` each without having to type `@@@@@` in the code?

I tried something like `print(5*"@", 4*"\n")` but it obviously didn't work.

Answer (score 6):

You can use the following:

```
(5 * '@' + '\n') * 4
```

Note that this is much less clear than `'@@@@@\n' * 4`.

Answer (score 3):

How about you loop over the print statement 4 times?

```
for _ in range(4):
    print(5 * '@')
```

Or, use `+` to append the newline, and multiply the result by 4:

```
print((5 * '@' + '\n') * 4)
```

Or, use a list and `.join()` the elements with newlines:

```
print('\n'.join([5 * '@'] * 4))
```

Answer (score 1):

```
for x in [5 * "@"] * 4:
    print x
```

or:

```
print "\n".join([5 * "@"] * 4)
```

Answer (score 0):

one line version:

```
>>> print 4 * ("%s\n" % (5*"@"))
```

or

```
>>> print 4 * ( 5*"@" + "\n" )
```

multiline:

```
>>> for x in xrange(4):
    print "@@@@@"


@@@@@
@@@@@
@@@@@
@@@@@
```

Answer (score 0):

You could do `print "%s\n" % (5*"@")*4`